# Using Maven to Install a Java Library

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am new to Maven. Recently I have downloaded and installed Maven successfully on my Windows 8 machine. I am trying to use an API created by Twilio for sending text messages.

To use the `Twilio API`, Twilio requires that you have Maven installed on your machine. On the [Twilio website](http://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install#installation) there are setup instructions for the API.

I am using `NetBeans`. After installing Maven I do not know if there is any special integration that I must do to use Maven in NetBeans. Please give me some step by step instructions on what I need to do, that would be very helpful. Or, if anyone knows of a link that gives clear instructions to a new Maven user for API integration with NetBeans, that would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure NetBeans comes with Maven already, but anyway, go to Tools>Options>Java>Maven
And point it to the folder where you installed Maven on your computer.
You can create a new Maven project and then use the Twilio API (or any other) if you include the proper dependencies they require in your pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>3.4.5</version>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this is to follow the steps described on the webpage http://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install#installation

Create a `pom.xml` file in the root of your project. Add the following dependency in the dependecies section.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[This maven tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) gives you a brief introduction to how to setup your maven project.

Put your own src-code in `src/main/java`, run mvn compile and you should be set to use the classes from Twilio.

Answer (score 2):

git clone git@github.com:twilio/twilio-java
cd twilio-java
mvn install # Requires maven, download from http://maven.apache.org/download.html

is 'mvn' command available on the command prompt. You can check this by opening a new command prompt and type mvn

If you get a command not found, then you need to add mvn to the PATH

once you are able to find maven, then you can do "mvn install" in the twilio-java directory and twilio-java artifacts would get installed to the local maven repository- which would be /.m2/repository/

And then we could think of adding that artifact as a dependency to the maven project that you would be creating in NETBEANS